# Automated move of files to various subfolders based on list in Win7

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, automation

I have to move a lot of files to different folders for my job. I'm able to get a human-readable list of what files go where from our internal webpage. What I'd like to do is automate the file movement process on Windows 7.

I have around 450 files, all named with digits and letters, e.g. 1.mp4, 2.mp4, 2a.mp4, etc. I need to put them into specific folders, also numbered. E.g. Folder 6431, folder 2315.

Here's a sample of the list I get:

```
High Performance Dance Center (AK) - 3356

4 dances competing
Finals

#20 3:57 PM      Flower Festival
#120    9:27 PM  Landfill
#158    4:37 PM  Ladies With An Attitude
#230    9:02 PM  Sound of Silence`

Karla Pattavina's Dance Academy (AL) - 172

5 dances competing
Finals
#47 5:48 PM         Turn to Stone
#69 6:54 PM         Taking Flight
#93 8:06 PM         All I Want
#211    8:01 PM     I Look To You
#255    10:30 PM    unDefined
```

So files 20.mp4, 120.mp4, 158.mp4, and 230.mp4 go into folder 3356. Files 47.mp4, 69.mp4, 93.mp4, 211.mp4, and 255.mp4 go into folder 172. Now just repeat this for 400+ files in 20-40 different folders.

I can get our webmaster to generate the list in a different format than it is now, but what's the best way to move files like this? I would like to use a batch script, or really anything that doesn't require special software. The more fool-proof the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q28186729.txt) DO (
 CALL :analyse %%a
)

GOTO :EOF
::
:analyse
:: line may begin "#number"
SET "filename=%1"
IF "%filename:~0,1%"=="#" ECHO(move "%sourcedir%\%filename:~1%.mp4" "%destdir%\%dirname%\"&GOTO :eof
: dirnl
SET "filename=%2"
IF NOT DEFINED filename GOTO :EOF
IF "%3"=="" IF "%1"=="-" SET "dirname=%2"&MD "%destdir%\%2\" 2>nul&GOTO :EOF
SHIFT
GOTO dirnl
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q28186729.txt` containing your data for my testing.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

That was an easy one!

Comment: That successfully creates all my folders, but nothing gets moved into them. Very strange. I ran it with cmd /k to keep the prompt window open. The window shows the proper file names and paths, yet the files don't get moved.

Comment: You could add a `pause` line just before the `goto :eof` to keep the window open - or preferably, run the command directly from the prompt - select programs/accessories/command prompt Right-click and `send to` desktop; run from the icon created. The clean methd to close the window is `quit`. I'll also edit-in my normal 'how to get it to work' waffle which I'd omitted.

Comment: Ah, yes of course. `ECHO(MOVE` would just, well, echo the move command and not actually execute it. This is perfect! Thank you!